# Changing values in matrix in matlab via a function call

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, user-defined-functions

I have a matrix full of zeros. I would then like to change one 0 at a time to the value one. It has to be me deciding which element I would like to change. I have tried the following:

```
    classdef project < handle

properties
      scheme
end

methods
    function obj = project(antpro,antmed)
        obj.scheme = zeros(antpro,antmed);         
    end      

    function obj = AddEmployee(pronav,mednav)
        % Function adding a employee to the scheme
        obj.scheme(pronav,mednav) = 1;
    end
 end
```

end

I hope it is somewhat clear what I want to do. When I run this code i get the message:
"Undefined function 'AddEmployee' for input arguments of type 'double'."

I really do not understand this, as all my files are located in the same folder, and that it is the path for my matlab session.

Thank you in advance
/Lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of methods in matlab requires passing `obj` as a first argument. Below is a link for the corresponding matlab documentation:
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/ordinary-methods.html#brdqipw-1

Comment: This made little sense? Are you saying that my first method, need to be 
function obj = project(antpro,antmed)
        obj = zeros(antpro,antmed);         
    end

instead?

Comment: I would try this declaration:function AddEmployee(obj,pronav,mednav) The first method seems ok

Comment: This has solved my problem! Thank you very much, thought I had tried that already, but apparently not. It seems in the documentation that you can use both? Maybe I had misinterpreted!?

Comment: My matlab seems inconsistent in what it accepts.. Nice when you are programming.. I try something and it works, and creates something just like it for other values, and then stops working.. well well..

Answer (score 0):

This is a class and you need to create an instance of it and call its `AddEmployee` method (although I'm not sure how you managed to create it without knowing this).

```
>> prj = project(); % Create an instance
>> prj.AddEmployee('a', 'name'); % Call a method in the instance
```

Sounds like you will probably find the [this information](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/begin-using-object-oriented-programming.html) of use. See also the [Object Oriented Programming](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html) documentation.

Comment: I just thought that I created the instance as I created the matrix with zeros. All I thought I needed was a function to change the values in the already exiting matrix, but that might apprently not be a possibility..

Comment: It sounds like you want the method to live outside the scope of this isntantiation.  Can you make the function static?

Comment: I am sorry to report, that i do not know what that means, and sorry to say that I must be the most hopeless case in this forum, so please accept my foolishness..